# Is there any example of code in python which i get table of numbers from the range in the first table?

Tags: python, excel

In my first table I have columns: `indeks`, `il`, `start` and `stop`. The last two define a range. I need to list (in a new table) all numbers in the range from `start` to `stop`, but also save `indeks` and the other values belonging to the range.

This table shows what kind of data I have (sample):

| ID | Indeks | Start | Stop | il |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A1 | 1 | 3 | 25 |
| 1 | B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 |
| 2 | C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 |
| 3 | D1 | 900 | 2500 | 20 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And this is the table I want to get:

| Indeks | Start | Stop | il | kod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 3 | 25 | 1 |
| A1 | 1 | 3 | 25 | 2 |
| A1 | 1 | 3 | 25 | 3 |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 31 |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 32 |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 33 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 53 |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 54 |
| B1 | 31 | 55 | 5 | 55 |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 36 |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 37 |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 38 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 898 |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 899 |
| C1 | 36 | 900 | 865 | 900 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

*EDITET*

```
lidy=pd.read_excel('path' )
lid=pd.DataFrame(lidy)
output = []
for i in range (0,len(lid)):
    for j in range (lid.iloc[i,1],lid.iloc[i,2]+1):
        y=((lid.iloc[i,0], j))output.append(y)
print(output)
```

OR

```
lidy=pd.read_excel('path' )
lid=pd.DataFrame(lidy)
for i in range (0,len(lid)):
    for j in range (lid.iloc[i,1],lid.iloc[i,2]+1):
        y=((lid.iloc[i,0], j))
        print(y)
```

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What does the `dataframe` tag mean: What kind of dataframe, Pandas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain my problem without this screenshot. Image shows sample data, not original data.

Comment: These are my first steps here. Thanks for your help and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**(1 - preferred)** Use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) (in combination with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as engine): The Excel-file I'm using is named `data.xlsx`, and sheet `Sheet1` contains your data. Then this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
df["kod"] = df[["Start", "Stop"]].apply(
    lambda row: range(row.iat[0], row.iat[1] + 1), axis=1
)
df = df.iloc[:, 1:].explode("kod", ignore_index=True)
with pd.ExcelWriter("data.xlsx", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet2", index=False)
```

should produce the required output in sheet `Sheet2`. The work is done by putting the required `range()`s in the new column `kod`, and then [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)-ing it.

**(2)** Use only `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename="data.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
rows = ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)
# Reading the required column names
data = [list(next(rows)[1:]) + ["kod"]]
for row in rows:
    # Read the input data (a row)
    base = list(row[1:])
    # Create the new data via iterating over the the given range 
    data.extend(base + [n] for n in range(base[1], base[2] + 1))
if "Sheet2" in wb.sheetnames:
    del wb["Sheet2"]
ws_new = wb.create_sheet(title="Sheet2")
for row in data:
    ws_new.append(row)
wb.save("data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of this codes are not what I want to get. I wrote some code and now I can print some list of numbers  but I don't know how to save it as a dataframe and then in xlsx. In edited post you can see the code.